# Configuring mutt to send e-mail over an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, smtp, ssh-tunnel, mutt

I want to be able to send email from mutt through an SSH tunnel  I can SSH into the SMTP server, but I don't know how to tell mutt how to use the tunnel to send e-mail.

Can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using remote SMTP is described here: https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MuttFaq/Sendmail

So with the tunnel you'd set up your SMTP to localhost, but with the tunnel port.
Eg. you create tunnel 8025->25 on remote:

```
ssh -L8025:smtp.example.com:25 serv.example.com
```

And in Mutt configuration (`.muttrc`) you put:

```
set smtp_url="smtp://username@localhost:8025/"
```

BTW. Using remote POP/IMAP here: https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MuttFaq/RemoteFolder

Comment: good advice.  I was wrong though, I didn't even need an SSH tunnel, just TLS.

Comment: oh, you should have asked ;-) I've though that you're doing poor man's VPN ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have ssh with local port forwarding running on your own. Both mutt and Neomutt have config option `tunnel`.

- [mutt docs](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#tunnel)
- [neomutt docs](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference.html#3-438-%C2%A0tunnel)

> tunnel
> Type: string
> Default: (empty)
>
> Setting this variable will cause mutt to open a pipe to a command instead of a raw socket. You may be able to use this to set up preauthenticated connections to your IMAP/POP3/SMTP server. Example:
>
> `set tunnel="ssh -q mailhost.net /usr/local/libexec/imapd"`
>
> Note: For this example to work you must be able to log in to the remote machine without having to enter a password.
>
> When set, Mutt uses the tunnel for all remote connections. Please see “account-hook” in the manual for how to use different tunnel commands per connection.

example:

```sh
neomutt -F /dev/null \
  -e 'set tunnel="ssh host.example.com' \
  test@example.com \
  < /tmp/msg
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example from the linked documentation instead of only the link.

Comment: I just added minimal config example. Thanks for pointing this out.